# Setting RPC timeout for DsGetDcName

Tags: active-directory, rpc, domaincontroller

While invoking DsGetDcName when domain controller is unreachable, or when the network is switched the API takes a long time ( 40s ) to detect failure.

The API actually does a RPC call, which might be the reason for the time. I am trying to get a timeout of 10s configured for RPC calls so that it does not block.

Any inputs appreciated !!

Some reference material for this:

The Domain Controller lookup is a RPC call
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/247811/how-domain-controllers-are-located-in-windows

Setting Timeout in registry which does not seem to work
http://www.expta.com/2012/06/new-best-practice-for-rpc-timeouts-in.html

Updating the timeout from RpcBindingSetOption 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375611(v=vs.85).aspx